# Selecting columns in a dataframe with integer-named columns

Tags: python, pandas

In the following dataframe I can access two columns by using a list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), index=[0,.5,1.,1.5], columns=['10', '20', '30', '40'])
df[['10','20']]
        10        20
0.0  1.048499  0.339459
0.5 -0.802472  1.348099
1.0  0.552306 -2.117145
1.5  1.737839  1.062061
```

When the column names are numbers (integers in this case), the same slicing returns an error

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), index=[0,.5,1.,1.5], columns=[10, 20, 30, 40])
df[[10,20]]
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How do I get the same result when the column names are numbers instead of strings?

Any tips on this please??

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the integers aren't converted to chars?

try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), index=[0,.5,1.,1.5], columns=[10, 20, 30, 40])
df[["10","20"]]
```

or:

df[[1,2]]

Comment: No, this returns `KeyError: "['10' '20'] not in index"`